# Name analysis results

Tags: r

I want to find the gender of names of an example like this

```
names <- data.frame(names = c("john Bruck", "Anna Rufel", "Monica", "Adam"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

so I use this:

```
library(genderizeR)

givenNames = findGivenNames(names, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

How is it possible to receive an output like this:

```
name gender
john Bruck male
Anna Rufel female
Monica female
Adam male
```

Comment: that package is removed from `CRAN`

Comment: @akrun is there any different way to recognize gender?

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you. I am interesting for a simple testing solution like this option `library(gender); gender(c("john", "nathalie"), method = "demo")` but I can find how to receive for more than one the results

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to get in any gender-related discussion.
However, purely from a technical perspective, you can install the github version:

https://github.com/kalimu/genderizeR

Comment: I am interesting for a simple testing solution like this option library(gender); gender(c("john", "nathalie"), method = "demo") but I can find how to receive for more than one the results